# Active Directory on server 2008 R2 default administrator acct cant rdp into domain computers

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, rdp

Hey everybody, I just started messing with AD about three days ago, but I have one machine running as the AD DC computer, and another that joined the domain with no problems. The only wierd thing is that I can RDP into the Domain Controller no problem, but I cant rdp into the other Domain Computer using my default administrator acct, an acct I made and gave domain admin privs to, but I CAN login using the built in windows administrator acct. Any words of wisdom? I figure its not a firewall problem because I can use the local acct to rdp into it, its not a domain issue because I have a share folder between the DC and that particular Domain Computer so Im not sure.

Comment: Are you trying to login as a domain member?  domain\your admin account?  When you are typing whichever admin account you might be entering, local_computer\local admin, which is the default, or local_computer\domain admin.  Just be sure what domain you are trying to access with what account.

Comment: yes sir, DOMAIN\useracct notation

Answer (score 1):

What error message does it give you when the login fails?

I'm gonna base this answer on the assumption that it's the `To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the allow log on through terminal services right` error, since that seems likely.. but let me know if that's inaccurate.

What's probably happening is that the User Rights Assignment for RDP is set to something strange.  Hop on a DC, and check out the Resultant Set of Policy for the server in the Group Policy Management Console tool.  Under `User Rights Assignment`, there are two settings to be concerned with: Allow and Deny log on through Remote Desktop/Terminal Services.  Deny should be empty, and Allow should contain `Administrators` and `Remote Desktop Users`.

If they're set wrong, the tool will display where the settings are coming from (either a specific group policy object, or the Local Security policy); it can then be corrected there.

Comment: I forgot to mention what the error was! This is the wierdest part, the error says "The credentials that were used on blah blah blah did not work" and at the bottom "The login attempt failed" almost like I used the wrong password. For when I try to login using the DOMAIN\username syntax for my domain Administrator and my user acct with domain admin privs. The local administrator acct works fine. This is on a 2 hr old install and I changed nothing that wasnt default. Ill give your fix a shot as soon as I get home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double check that RDP is enabled on the workstation. Right click My Computer > Properties > Remote Access. There should be a check box for remote access. This is for XP.

The defautl administrator account you're talking about, is that the domain administrator account? If so, double check that domain admins is a part of the local administrator group on the domain PC.

Comment: No the default administrator account is the pre-domain account he is using, I believe.  The default admin has RDP rights.  For some reason a domain administrator account isn't being allowed RDP access.

Comment: Exactly! I gave a better explanation of whats happening one answer down.